# Парсинг с последущим выводом в бота ТГ

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, telebot

Пишу бота, но столкнулся с проблемой, что когда нажимаю на кнопку "Анекдот" получается ошибка NameError: name 'num' is not defined. Did you mean: 'sum'?. Как её решить, ведь мне нужный мне результат находится в переменной "num". (print оставил чтобы можно было проверить, парсятся ли вообще анекдоты)

```
import random
from telebot import types
import os
from sys import argv
from sys import exit as sysex

from lxml import etree
import requests
from html2text import html2text

f = open('data/army.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
army = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()

f = open('data/thinks.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
thinks  = f.read().split('\n')
f.close()


bot = telebot.TeleBot('№№№')

def get_banek(addr):
    req = requests.get('http://baneks.ru/' + addr)
    req.encoding = 'utf-8'

    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    root = etree.fromstring(req.text, parser)
    li = root.xpath("//section[@class='anek-view']")
    text = etree.tostring(li[0].find('article'))
    return html2text(text.decode()).replace("\\-", "-")

def main():
    if len(argv) == 1:
        num = 'random'
    elif argv[1].isdecimal():
        num = argv[1]
    print(get_banek(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
        
        markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1=types.KeyboardButton("Анекдот")
        item2=types.KeyboardButton("Поговорка")
        item3=types.KeyboardButton("Афоризм")
        markup.add(item1)
        markup.add(item2)
        markup.add(item3)
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Нажми: \nАнекдот для получения анекдота\nПоговорка — для получения русской народной поговорки\n Афоризм - для получения армейского авторского афоризма',  reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def handle_text(message):

    if message.text.strip() == 'Афоризм' :
        answer = random.choice(army)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

    if message.text.strip() == 'Поговорка':
        answer = random.choice(thinks)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)

    if message.text.strip()== 'Анекдот' :
        answer = main()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
        
bot.polling()
```

Comment: `answer = num` ваша функция не знает что такое num , эта переменная нигде не объявлена в этом хэндлере

Comment: возьмусь предположить что вам надо туда вставить значение из функции `main`. Тогда просто возвращайте значение  `get_banek(num)` `из main` и вызовите ее  `answer = main()`

Comment: Вызвал из функции main, но теперь почему то теперь ошибка с пустым сообщением
"telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty"

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы было понятно что именно вы сделали)

Comment: вы не возвращаете значение в функции main. Уберите `print` и добавьте `return`

Comment: Теперь понял и всё получилось. Спасибо!)

Comment: так же нет никакого смысла в этой строчке `if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()` переместите ее вниз и замените на `if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling()`